# Robotlegs 2 migration - Dynamic view

Tags: actionscript-3, dependency-injection, migration, robotlegs, robot-legs-problem

I used RB1 in my projects the following way: I had externally-loaded GFX with linkage names. I did something like this:

```
injector.mapClass(MyView, MyView);
var ClassReference : Class = getDefinitionByName(id) as Class;
mediatorMap.mapView(ClassReference, MyMediator);
```

In mediator I used `getViewComponent` and passed it into the `MyView` class.
`MyView` was injected to the mediator.

Now in RB2 I have no possibility to take view by `getViewComponent`.
Also I cannot inject view into Mediator, since I get its class only in runtime by `getDefinitionByName`.

Could you please give me some piece of advice on how to handle this?

Thank you!